# Insert One Component into a CDK Portal

Tags: angular

My goal is to have a slide-out menu (sidebar) into which I can insert different components.

I currently have a sidebar component that is dynamically created but I am struggling with how to pass in a component and attach it to the sidebar.

I've prepared a little example of where I am currently at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sh1quy

`this.sidebarService.open( ContentComponent )` should created the `SidebarComponent` and then insert `ContentComponent` into it.